# EmberJs: Not able to resolve config/environment.js from a service

Tags: javascript, ember.js, resolver

Ember version - ~2.8.0

This might seem really simple, but it has got on to nerves after hours of looking through for a fault.

I am trying to simply import the config/environment.js file into a service(at app/services/myservice.js) and make use of the contents. like this -

> import config from "../config/environment";

But, all i get is `"Cannot read property 'APP' of undefined"` in the console, if i do `config.APP`. Even though environment.js is present physically, under `demo-app/config/environment.js`.

i am confused, if i am missing some convention, or some setting somewhere that needs to be present, in order for this to resolve correctly.

Please help.

Also(Although this was obvious), if i change the import as `import config from "../../config/environment";`, it says `Could not find module 'config/environment' imported from 'demo-app/services/myservice'`

I do understand the app folder is skipped in the resolution. i.e. the physical address of demo-app/app/something... becomes demo-app/something... . But some one please explain why it may not be resolving. It is in the fresh installation of the App.

Comment: Include the code for `app/services/myservice.js`, like how/where are you accessing it ?

Answer (score 2):

`import ENV from 'demo-app/config/environment';` works for me (`demo-app` is a package name and usually it's the same as your project root directory name). A big advantage of this method is that you don't need to think how much `../` you need to put, just drop the same line in any of your files.

Comment: Hi, @Gennady I tried your suggestion. Still the same. I don't think it has a problem in making up the path untill the package (app name). But to trickle down after that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `resolveRegistration` of `ApplicationInstance` such as:

```
let conf = Ember.getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment');
```

Pass your service as `this`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the correct relative path in your case,

`import config from "./../config/environment";`